# How to access to data in block "do" swift2

Tags: try-catch, swift2

im pretty new to Swift, im making a little Tic Tac Toe game with Multipeer Connectivity to start, and I encountered a problem. 
To receive my data I made a "do" block as:

```
       do{
           let data = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataToTake,
           options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
         }catch let error as NSError?{
         print(error)
         }
```

later on, i would like to access to data outside from the "do" block, but i cannot, as outside "do" i cant see data. Can anyone help me? Dont go hard on me, as i said im pretty new to swift! Thanks!

Comment: If the JSON deserialization failed then you have no data. You have to decide first how you want to proceed in that case.

Comment: I see, can you give me an example how to do that please? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the data object outside the scope of the do catch block. To access it outside of that block you have to define a var before you execute the block:

```
var data: AnyObject?
do {
    data = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataToTake, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
} catch {
    print(error)
}

print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks also for your help!

Answer (score 0):

general example with common mistake. in do closure we can define a 'local' var with the same name with unwanted results

```
var j = 1
var k = 0
do {
    var j = 0
    // .....
    j = 2
    k = j
}
print(j,k) // 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and for the example! Now i got it!